# Title: Mixed Content Error when launching Ionic application in Android Studio

Tags: spring-boot, android-studio, ionic-framework

I have developed a hybrid application using Ionic with Angular for the frontend and Spring Boot for the backend REST API. When attempting to launch my application in Android Studio, I encounter a mixed content error.

When i launch ionic everything works perfectly but when i deploy it in android i cant log in

Error:
In the application console, I receive the following error:

"Mixed Content: The page at 'https://localhost/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://AdressIp:Port/doctors/login'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

I added this line on Manifest but still the same problem :

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Answer (score 0):

if you are using capacitor, check this section "allowMixedContent" in https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config , greetings.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34894834)

Answer (score 0):

1. Change https by http in capacitor.config.ts
   In your capacitor.config.ts file temporarily change androidScheme:
   'https' to androidScheme: 'http' this allows you to work with http://
2. Add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in the manifest file
   then if you're using android, go to your
   android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml folder

in the  section, add
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true",

after addition you should have

```
<application
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
 >
...
</application>
```